# What replaces the question mark in the blood relation problem?

Tags: logical-deduction, family

If A + B means A is the father of B If A × B means A is the sister of B
If A $ B means A is the wife of B If A % B means A is the mother of B
If A ÷ B means A is the son of B

What should come in place of the question mark, to establish that T is the sister-in-law of Q in
the given expression ?

R % T × P ? J $ Q + V

Options:

(1) ÷

(2) percent(%)

(3) ×

(4) dollar sign

(5) Either $ or ×

Please answer this with the help of a family tree or any other structural method if possible.

Comment: Please add proper attribution for all of your recent problems like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer

> 3) $\times$

T is the sister-in-law in Q if

> Either Q is married to the sibling of T or Q is the sibling of T's spouse.

Hence

> Since we don't establish a spouse for T in the above expression, it must be that Q is married to the sibling of T. This means that J must be the sibling of T and also the sibling of P and so the only given operation that works is $\times$

Comment: Can you assist me with a family tree for this?